# Having trouble accessing my phone via USB

Tags: debian, filesystems

(I've searched the web for people that have had my exact problem, and couldn't find any, so if this is a repeat question I won't be offended by having this pulled, but I would appreciate being redirected towards the answer; seeing as I can't find it.)

I've just switched from Lubuntu to Gnewsense [Gnewsense runs on a debian base last I checked]. On Lubuntu I used to be able to plug my phone in via USB and then access the files straight from the gui take what I've downloaded on the phone and paste it to a random location on my computer, but after switching to the new OS: I've find that when I first plug in my phone the folder containing my phone's files appears in the desktop, when I open the folder: alk of the files that should be listed in my phone flash within the window for a very brief moment, the window closes and my phone disappears from the desktop. I can still access my phone while it remains plugged in from the file directory, but it acts as though it's empty and when I refresh: it loads for an indefinite period of time. I can repeat this consistently by unplugging the usb and plugging it back in.

Please note: I'm still warming up to the terminal (I know cd, pwd, dd, ect... but I'm not a total connoisseur yet, so simple explanations in addition to code would be appreciated), also note: that by switching to Gnewsense I've bricked the wireless card, so any solutions that involve a download won't be of assistance in this case. I don't mean to be ungrateful, I won't mind a little programming practice if it comes to that, although I feel it may just be a permissions error that's just my intuition and I wouldn't know how to fix it either way.

Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Run `dmesg | tail` in a terminal. Plug in phone and do the same. Then do the same after opening the folder. If needed, use `dmesg | tail -n NN` where `NN` is number of lines you want to view from end of *dmesg*. Alternatively do `dmesg -w` if implemented. (That will keep spitting out data as it is logged. Ctrl+C to quit.) If any *(seemingly)* relevant data/messages, copy and paste in your post by [edit]ing your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Next you’ll need to create a static mount point for MTP attached devices:

```
sudo mkdir /media/MTPdevice
sudo chmod 775 /media/MTPdevice
sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/MTPdevice
```

if you don’t already know your device’s idVendor and idProduct, you can determine them by connecting your phone via USB and querying it using MTP.  Make sure your device is in MTP mode

try this command

```
  mtp-detect
```

As soon as the VID and PID appear you can cancel the command (CTRL-C).  If the VID and PID aren’t displayed immediately after the device is listed, MTP should eventually display “idVendor: 04e8″ and “idProduct: 6860″ in the output.

Next you’ll need to add a rule to your USB system handler to properly detect and mount your device using your favourite text editor as root:

```
 gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Add the following, on a single line (be sure to replace  and  with the values you got from mtp-detect):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="<vendorId>", ATTR{idProduct}=="<productId>", MODE="0666"
```

After you save the file and exit your editor, disconnect your phone and restart udev:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Now when you connect your Android phone, tablet, etc. it should automatically mount for you at /media/MTPdevice.